# Do different types of recursion have different memory complexities?

Tags: python, recursion, memory, space-complexity

I was wondering if the 2 recursive functions below have different memory complexities:

1

```
def f(x):
    if x == 100:
        return 1
    return 1 + f(x + 1)
res = f(1) 
res # evaluates to 100
```

2

```
res = 1
def g(x):
    global res
    if x == 100:
        return
    res += 1
    g(x + 1)
g(1)
res # also evaluates to 100
```

From my understanding, it appears that since `f`'s recursive calls are being returned, Python must keep all 100 function calls in the stack frame until `x` reaches 100. On the other hand, `g`'s recursive calls are not returned, which means that the stack frame only needs to keep 1 function call at any given time. Therefore, `f` has linear memory complexity while `g` has constant. Is my understanding correct? Thanks!

Comment: Your understanding would be correct if Python optimized tail recursion. This is called "TCO" (tail call optimization). The latter form of recursion would be called *tail recursion*, since the recursive call is the last instruction of the function. Some languages (e.g. Lua) require `return tail_call(...)` for tail recursion to work.